# How to find the intersection of a singly linked list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to write an algorithm to find the intersection of a singly linked list. For this problem, the node of intersection does not actually have to be the same node object (i.e. it doesn't have to be the same memory location), the lists just have to have the exact same values from the node of intersection to the end of the lists. I have written a horribly inefficient algorithm for this in cubic time. I'm sure there is a better, probably recursive way to do this, but I can't quite figure it out. Any ideas?

For this problem, the intersection of two lists is a value for which all subsequent values in both lists are exactly identical. For example, given:
list 1 = {1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 12}
list 2 = {8, 9, 6, 4, 12}
The algorithm should return 6.

Here is my current solution: I look through each list for common elements, and when I find one, I check to see if the lists are identical from that element on.

```
public static boolean compareFrom(Node a, Node b) {
    Node current1 = a, current2 = b;
    while (current1 != null) {
        if (current2 == null
                || !(current1.getElem().equals(current2.getElem()))) {
            return false;
        }
        current1 = current1.getNext();
        current2 = current2.getNext();
    }
    if (current2 == null)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static Node intersection(SinglyLinkedList list1,
        SinglyLinkedList list2) {
    Node current1 = list1.head, current2 = list2.head;
    while (current1 != null) {
        while (current2 != null) {
            if (current1.getElem().equals(current2.getElem())
                    && compareFrom(current1, current2))
                return current1;
            else
                current2 = current2.getNext();
        }
        current2 = list2.head;
        current1 = current1.getNext();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you define the intersection (give some well fleshed out examples) and show your current code so that others may help you better?

Comment: @abaratham can you share your algorithm? It can help to find out what's to improve in it

Comment: @abaratham by "the intersection of two lists is a value for which all subsequent values in both lists are exactly identical" would it also return 4? or just 6 and if so why just 6?

Comment: Just 6, it returns the first element that fits the definition of an intersection

Comment: I would start the search from the last elements

Comment: Yes, I also had that idea, but it is a singly linked list, so you don't have access to the previous elements. My idea was to recurse to the tail and somehow use return values to access the previous elements but I'm not sure how that would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm sure there is a better, probably recursive way to do this, but I can't quite figure it out. Any ideas?

I'd construct a reversed list in O(n) time, then check the paired elements from the two lists, again in O(n) time.

(Or if you have the lists stored in two vectors, you can start by comparing a[m-i] and b[n-i] with i from 1 to the minimum between m and n):

```
 {1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 12} and {8, 9, 6, 4, 12}
 x := -1
 a[5] = b[4] = 12 so x := 12
 a[4] = b[3] = 4 so x := 4
 a[3] = b[2] = 6 so x := 6
 a[2] != b[1] so break
```

Intersection is 6.

## Without additional structures

We can scan both lists.

First of all we need to "sync" the two lists, which is O(n), and we obtain the list depth of A and B.

Armed with this number, we advance the longer list by the appropriate number of positions. If we have A with 7 elements and B with 4, we advance A by three. We know that there's no possibility for any element of A before the third to be an intersection, because the A subchain would be longer than the whole B.

i = 0 here.

Now we compare the first available element of A', let us call it A'(i), with the first available element of B, B(i).

If they are equal, then A'(i) is a **candidate** to being an intersection, but we can't be sure yet.

We advance A' and B and fetch A'(i+1) and B(i+1).

If we get another identical match, we do nothing: our first candidate is still going strong.

If we *do not* get a match, then our candidate couldn't have been valid and we discard it, setting cand to NULL.

Loop.

At the end we will have done more comparisons than the reverse-list method, but we will either have NULL or the *latest element that is a head of a common chain*.

Comment: Damn, I can't believe I didn't think of that one. Thanks

Comment: Out of curiousity, can you think of a way to do it without creating additional data structures or modifying the original ones?

Comment: I think so. Please check my logic, it's late night here :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Find length of both lists - 0(n)
2. Traverse the longer list up until the difference of these lengths
3. Now traverse both lists together and keep comparing element values

   ```
   public ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode headA, ListNode headB) {

   int first = 0, second = 0;
   if (headA == null || headB == null) return null;
   ListNode temp = headA;
   first  = findLen(headA);
   second  = findLen(headB);

   if (first > second){
       return findIntersection(headA, headB, first-second);
   }
   return findIntersection(headB, headA, second-first);

   }

   public ListNode findIntersection(ListNode longerList, ListNode shorterList, int diff){

   while(diff != 0){
       longerList = longerList.next;
       diff--;
   }

   while (longerList != null){
       if (longerList == shorterList) return longerList;
       longerList = longerList.next;
       shorterList = shorterList.next;
   }
   return null;
   }

   public int findLen(ListNode a){
   int len = 0;
   while (a != null){
       len++;
       a = a.next;
   }
   return len;
   }
   ```

   }